# How to hide dividing lines in a p:datatable

Tags: primefaces, datatable

I try to hide the row separators in a Sub-Datatable in my JSF-Application but it doesn't work. I'm also using Primefaces 6.0.

```
            <p:column style="font-size:10pt;vertical-align:top;width:50%">
                <f:facet name="header"></f:facet>
                <p:dataTable cellspacing="0%" id="iconTable" value="#{bla.kek}" var="lol" style="width:104%;margin-right:0%;margin-left:-2%;margin-top:-0.75%;margin-bottom:-0.75%;border-top:none;border-bottom:none;">
                <f:facet name="header" style=" display:none"></f:facet>
                    <p:column style="width:5%;text-align:center;border:0px;padding:0px;margin:0px" styleClass="borderless">
                    #{doesnt.matter}
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column style="width:95%;font-size:8pt;vertical-align:top;border:0px;padding:0px;margin:0px">
                    #{blablabla.blablabla}
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
            </p:column>
```

Sorry for those names but I think the table content doesn't affect the design in this case. Also sorry for the repetitive code. I hope you can help me find the solution :)

Comment: Don't style inline, create css rules with selectors that apply to the generated html.

Comment: And keep in mind that client-side it is all html and so the generated html and css is waaaay more important than a facelts snipped or being it jsf